# Typescript strongly typed key value pair declaration

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I would like to declare a TypeScript interface for such json structure:

```html
{ 
404: function() { alert( "page not found" ); }, 
400 : function() {...} 
}
```

the key is number, and the value is function, do you know how to declare an interface in TypeScript for such data constraints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Indexer

You *can* use numbers as keys in JavaScript if you use `[]` key access...

Let's start with your desired code...

```
var x = { 
    404: function() { alert( "page not found" ); }, 
    400 : function() { alert("...");} 
};

x.404();
```

The last statement above (the call to the `404` function) will error with `Missing ; before statement`, so you have to use...

```
x[404]();
```

While this will still get you type inference in TypeScript (`var a = x[404];` - `a` will be type `() => void`) - it won't give you good auto-completion.

Interface for this:

```
interface HttpCodeAlerts {
   [index: number]: () => void;
}
```

## With Auto-Completion

Normally in JavaScript and TypeScript it is recommended that you use safer names. Simplistically, you need to start them with a letter:

```
var x = { 
    E_404: function() { alert( "page not found" ); }, 
    E_400 : function() { alert("...");} 
};

x.E_404();
```

Interface for this:

```
interface HttpCodeAlerts {
    E_400: () => void;
    E_404: () => void;
}
```

## Framework Style

In most languages, the error is used more like this...

```
class HttpCode { 
    static OK = { responseCode: 200, reasonPhrase: 'Okay' };
    static NotFound = { responseCode: 404, reasonPhrase: 'Not Found' };
};

alert(HttpCode.NotFound.reasonPhrase);
```

Answer (score 4):

See [TypeScript Objects as Dictionary types as in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631557/typescript-objects-as-dictionary-types-as-in-c-sharp)

```
var map: { [code: number]: ()=>void; } = { };
//usage
map[404] = ()=> { alert("page not found"); }; 
map[400] = ()=> { alert("..."); };
map["some"] = "some"; //compile error

//all in once
var map: { [code: number]: ()=>void; } = {
   404: () => { alert( "page not found" ); }, 
   400: () => { alert( "..." )} 
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This can probably be one of the answer :-

```
export interface clientSideFunction{
    [code: number]: ()=>void;
}
```

use this interface by importing it using:-

```
import {clientSideFunction} from 'filePath';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid JSON structure thus not valid JavaScript (neither TypeScript).
Object keys should be strings. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2002981/1942494) numbers are always converted to strings.

Therefore I suggest to use explicit strings as keys in your JSON. Then you can model it in TypeScript like this:

```
interface ICodes {
    "404": () => void;
    [code: string]: () => void; // defines any string key to be function
}

var codes: ICodes = {
    "404": function () { alert("page not found"); },
    "400": function () {}
};

// call the function for code 404
codes["404"]();
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON, but it is valid JS. The two don't match completely