# Python 3, Are there any known security holes in ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, abstract-syntax-tree

Are there any known ways for [ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ast.html#ast-helpers)'s evaluation to not actually be safe?

If yes, are patches available for them?

(I already know about PyPy[sandbox], which is presumably more secure, but unless the answers are yes then no, my needs are minor enough that I won't be going that far.)

Answer (score 94):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) *formerly stated* it was safe, but [now contains the caveat](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95588):

> This function had been documented as “safe” in the past without defining what that meant. That was misleading. This is specifically designed not to execute Python code, unlike the more general `eval()`. There is no namespace, no name lookups, or ability to call out. But it is not free from attack: A relatively small input can lead to memory exhaustion or to C stack exhaustion, crashing the process. There is also the possibility for excessive CPU consumption denial of service on some inputs. Calling it on untrusted data is thus not recommended.
>
> It is possible to crash the Python interpreter due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler. It can raise `ValueError`, `TypeError`, `SyntaxError`, `MemoryError` and `RecursionError` depending on the malformed input.

Also, [according to the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Lib/ast.py#L56-L112), `literal_eval` parses the string to a Python AST (source tree), and returns only if it is a literal.

So, because the code is never executed, only parsed, [arbitrary code execution (ACE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) exploits should† be impossible. Denial of service (DOS) attacks **are** possible, however.

<sup>†known bugs of this nature will be patched, but there are the unknown bugs ;)</sup>

Comment: +1 The reason there aren't more answers here is that nothing more needs to be said.

Comment: Well, it's always difficult to prove that there is no risk, but the fact the code is never actually executed should help to convince that there is not much risk.

Comment: The risk is about the same as using Python itself.

Comment: unfortunately, i would like to use `ast.literal_eval()` in order to filter an input before passing it to `eval()` or `exec()`, which always represents a risk. but in fact, the source code seems to show that the input is pretty strictly filtered. i just hope that i did not miss an edge-case...

Comment: If the input is a litteral, literal_eval() will return the value. If the input is more than a literal (it contains code), then literal_eval() will fail, and there would be a risk in executing the code. In both case, literal_eval() does the job. Why do you want to use eval() or exec() after that ?

Comment: @madjar: oops, sorry, no i do not call `exec()` or `eval()` anymore. i was before, until i discovered `ast.literal_eval()`, it just  messed up in my brain...

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> code = '()' * 1000000
>>> ast.literal_eval(code)
[1]    3061 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python2
```

or possibly smaller will crash with `SIGSEGV` in **Python 2**. It might be exploitable under some conditions. This particular bug has been fixed in Python 3, but bugs may still exist in the AST parser.

Comment: you are using a operation in arguments to`literal_eval` (which is not a string or node), and has nothing to do with `literal_eval`.

Comment: @ProdiptaGhosh it is a string. There is a very good reason why I didn't expand those **million** parentheses in this answer!

Comment: The point is, you are first evaluating an expression (the string multiplied a gazillion time, it is an expression, **not** a string) **before** you are calling `literal_eval`, and that string expansion has **nothing** to do with `literal_eval` whatsoever. If things go write it gets the expanded string. If it goes wrong, python crashes even before `literal_eval` is called.

Comment: Ok, this makes things much clear. This seems a valid point. Not much to do with `literal_eval` but to the underlying `parse` and then the `compile` call, which segfault on exceeding max recursion limit. This is a valid point. I have reversed my vote.  This seems to be an [open issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue32758) for later versions as well

Comment: Seems a fair point but assuming you're using the `literla_eval(data)` function can't just put a `if len(data) < 10000:` just before to avoid this issue ?

Comment: In 3.8, I find that even a small input can cause `MemoryError` (*not* `RecursionError`). The limit appears to be 100 nested parentheses; I assume it is limited explicitly and specially.

Comment: In a [2022 issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95588) and later [patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/95919), the safety claims were updated to reflect that it is not safe from DOS attacks, just ACE attacks.