# Is it a best practice to use python ast library for operations like converting string to dict

Tags: python, json, type-conversion

I have been trying to convert a string of dictionary objects as given below

```
"{'Cmd': None, 'Hostname': None, 'Entrypoint': None, 'Env': None,     'OpenStdin': False, 
'Tty': False, 'Domainname': None, 'Image': u'nginx:latest', 'HostConfig':   
{'Binds': None, 'RestartPolicy': {}, 'NetworkMode': u'bridge', 'Dns': None, 
'Links': [], 'PortBindings': {}, 'DnsSearch': None, 'Privileged': False,
'VolumesFrom': []}, 'ExposedPorts': {}, 'User': None}"
```

to python dictionary.

But the solutions came up while searching were suggesting to use python ast library for the purpose. as

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(string)
```

And it works fine. But is ast library is built indented to solve problems like this ? Is there any good approach other than this to solve the problem ?

Comment: A better question might be: how are you ending up with *"a string of dictionary objects"* in the first place? If you're persisting data to a file, consider JSON (human-readable but limited to certain data types) or pickle (unreadable but works for pretty much any object) instead.

Comment: @ jonrsharpe This is a data that i get from a form post of a text area field. I am not able to parse it as json

Comment: Why are you taking that kind of input in that way? What's the *purpose* of this?

Comment: Why do you need the ast library? Couldn't you just use regular eval() ?

Comment: @EspenHaugsdal on data submitted through a web form? Are you nuts? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1933451/3001761

Comment: @  jonrsharpe This is a configuration. I have to take this input as it is. As you said i don't think using literal_eval  or eval is a good option and hence the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is ast library is built indented to solve problems like this ?

Your concern is valid. `ast.literal_eval`, just as the normal `eval`, were not primarily designed to deserialize data. And that's because *Python code was never designed to serialize data* in the first place.

But there isn't really anything exotic about it: under the hood, it uses the interpreter's built-in `compile()` (which is the same function CPython uses to parse normal code), but `literal_eval` will also generate and go through the AST, and will raise an exception if it contains anything other than literals.

In practice, there are two issues to you need to think about: security & performance. For the example you posted, performance shouldn't be much of an issue, so you should stick with `ast.literal_eval` (which is [thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710247/python-3-are-there-any-known-security-holes-in-ast-literal-evalnode-or-string) to be quite secure so far). If you're dealing with (much) larger dictionaries, however, then you're likely to approach some memory issues.

In that case and if possible, the saner choice by far would be to avoid serializing the data as Python code in the first place and use something like JSON. If not, consider converting the string to some other form before parsing it; you could, for example, use a regex to convert it to JSON first (the format is very similar) and then parse it with `json.loads`. But as long as you're not having performance issues, stick with `ast.literal_eval` and you should be fine.

In any case, no matter what you do, never, *never* use `eval`. It just leaves a gaping security hole for only a marginal benefit.