# Kubernetes Python client returns pod's JSON HTTP response from proxy verb as string with single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: json, kubernetes, proxy, kubernetes-python-client

I'm requesting some JSON data from a pod's web server via the Kubernetes API proxy verb. That is:

```
corev1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
res = corev1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_proxy_with_path(
    'mypod:5000', 'default', path='somepath', path2='somepath')
print(type(res))
print(res)
```

The call succeeds and returns a `str` containing the serialized JSON data from my pod's web service. Unfortunately, `res` now looks like this ... which isn't valid JSON at all, so `json.loads(res)` denies to parse it:

```
{'x': [{'xx': 'xxx', ...
```

As you can see, the stringified response looks like a Python dictionary, instead of valid JSON. Any suggestions as to how this convert safely back into either correct JSON or a correct Python `dict`?

Comment: res.replace("'",""")? ))

Comment: Not a good idea, as this breaks when there are escaped "'" inside the names or strings. Also, `eval()` isn't a good idea either, because then someone might attack my Kubernetes client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [core_v1_api.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py). The method calls generally accept a kwarg named `_preload_content`.

Setting this argument to `False` instructs the method to return the `urllib3.HTTPResponse` object instead of a processed `str`. You can then work directly with the data, which cooperates with `json.loads()`.

Example:

```py
corev1 = client.CoreV1Api()
res = corev1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_proxy_with_path(
    'mypod:5000', 'default', path='somepath', 
    path2='somepath', _preload_content=False)
json.loads(res.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem with executing on a pod and found a solution.
I guess it could work for you as well.

1. add the parameter _preload_content=False, to the stream call -> you receive a WSClient object
2. call run_forever(timeout=10) on it
3. Then you get the correct and unformatted string with .read_stdout()

For example:

```
wsclient_obj = stream(v1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, m
                    y_name,
                    'default',
                    command=['/bin/sh', '-c', 'echo $MY_VAR'],
                    stderr=True,
                    stdin=False,
                    stdout=True,
                    tty=False,
                    _preload_content=False
                )
wsclient_obj.run_forever(timeout=10)
response_str = wsclient_obj.read_stdout()
```

After that `json.loads(response_str)` will work :)

Answer (score 1):

After reading through some code of the Kubernetes Python client, it is now clear that `connect_get_namespaced_pod_proxy()` and `connect_get_namespaced_pod_proxy_with_path()` force the response body from the remote API call to be converted to `str` by calling `self.api_client.call_api(..., response_type='str', ...)` ([core_v1_api.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-client/python/master/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py)). So, we're stuck with the Kubernetes API client giving us only the string representation of the `dict()` representing the original JSON response body.

To convert the string back to a `dict()`, the [anwer to Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988251) suggests to use `ast.literal_eval()`. Wondering whether this is a sensible route to take, I've found the [answer to Is it a best practice to use python ast library for operations like converting string to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967453/is-it-a-best-practice-to-use-python-ast-library-for-operations-like-converting-s) says that it's a sensible thing to do.

```
import ast
corev1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
res = corev1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_proxy_with_path(
    'mypod:5000', 'default', path='somepath', path2='somepath')
json_res = ast.literal_eval(res)
```