# Is None really a built-in?

Tags: python, built-in, nonetype

I am trying to use Python's (2.7) `eval` in a (relatively) safe manner. Hence, I defined:

```
def safer_eval(string):
    """Safer version of eval() as globals and builtins are inaccessible"""
    return eval(string, {'__builtins__': {}})
```

As expected, the following does not work any more:

```
print safer_eval("True")
NameError: name 'True' is not defined
```

However, I can still eval a `"None"` string:

```
print safer_eval("None")
None
```

- So, is `None` not a built-in?
  They are at least both part of `__builtin__` ...
- Why is it still eval-able?
- How would I get rid of it, if I had to?

Comment: Why not just use `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: Yes, `None` is a built-in singleton object and a *keyword*.

Comment: Oh, that's a good one :) I most likely should use it instead of my approach.
However, my questions still stand. Why are the bools and None behaving differently here?

Comment: @NichtJens: because their names are reserved. In Python 3 `safer_eval('True')` will work too.

Comment: And there is no such thing as a 'safer' eval; the built-ins can still be referenced from other places. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: I read that one before, but thanks for pointing to it. However, there's a difference between it being "safe" from accidental errors (which it more or less should be now) and "safe" from on-purpose malice, right?

Comment: Maybe I'm biased (I'm involved in cybersecurity at work) but what sense does it make to look at a piece of code, say "Yeah, this is totally unsafe, but it's probably fine as long as nobody tries to abuse it"?

Comment: Does "I am the only one using it" count as valid answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`None` is a *constant* in Python, see the [*Keywords* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords):

> Changed in version 2.4: `None` became a constant and is now recognized by the compiler as a name for the built-in object `None`. Although it is not a keyword, you cannot assign a different object to it.

The compiler simply inserts a reference to the singleton `None` object whenever you name it:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(compile('None', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

`True` and `False` are built-ins in Python 2, which also means they can be masked.

In Python 3, `None`, `True` and `False` all are [now keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), and all three are materialised merely by naming them:

```
>>> eval('True', {'__builtins__': {}})
True
```

See [Guido van Rossum's blog post on why this was changed](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html).

Note that there is **nothing safe** about eval, even with `__builtins__` neutered, as it can still be referenced via other means:

```
>>> s = '''
... [
...     c for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()
...     if c.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'
... ][0]()._module.__builtins__
... '''
>>> eval(s, {'__builtins__': {}})
{'bytearray': <type 'bytearray'>, 'IndexError': <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>, 'all': <built-in function all>, 'help': Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object., 'vars': <built-in function vars>, 'SyntaxError': <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>, 'unicode': <type 'unicode'>, 'UnicodeDecodeError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>, 'memoryview': <type 'memoryview'>, 'isinstance': <built-in function isinstance>, 'copyright': Copyright (c) 2001-2015 Python Software Foundation.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 2000 BeOpen.com.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 1995-2001 Corporation for National Research Initiatives.
All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam.
All Rights Reserved., 'NameError': <type 'exceptions.NameError'>, 'BytesWarning': <type 'exceptions.BytesWarning'>, 'dict': <type 'dict'>, 'input': <built-in function input>, 'oct': <built-in function oct>, 'bin': <built-in function bin>, 'SystemExit': <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>, 'StandardError': <type 'exceptions.StandardError'>, 'format': <built-in function format>, 'repr': <built-in function repr>, 'sorted': <built-in function sorted>, 'False': False, 'RuntimeWarning': <type 'exceptions.RuntimeWarning'>, 'list': <type 'list'>, 'iter': <built-in function iter>, 'reload': <built-in function reload>, 'Warning': <type 'exceptions.Warning'>, '__package__': None, 'round': <built-in function round>, 'dir': <built-in function dir>, 'cmp': <built-in function cmp>, 'set': <type 'set'>, 'bytes': <type 'str'>, 'reduce': <built-in function reduce>, 'intern': <built-in function intern>, 'issubclass': <built-in function issubclass>, 'Ellipsis': Ellipsis, 'EOFError': <type 'exceptions.EOFError'>, 'locals': <built-in function locals>, 'BufferError': <type 'exceptions.BufferError'>, 'slice': <type 'slice'>, 'FloatingPointError': <type 'exceptions.FloatingPointError'>, 'sum': <built-in function sum>, 'getattr': <built-in function getattr>, 'abs': <built-in function abs>, 'exit': Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit, 'print': <built-in function print>, 'True': True, 'FutureWarning': <type 'exceptions.FutureWarning'>, 'ImportWarning': <type 'exceptions.ImportWarning'>, 'None': None, 'hash': <built-in function hash>, 'ReferenceError': <type 'exceptions.ReferenceError'>, 'len': <built-in function len>, 'credits':     Thanks to CWI, CNRI, BeOpen.com, Zope Corporation and a cast of thousands
    for supporting Python development.  See www.python.org for more information., 'frozenset': <type 'frozenset'>, '__name__': '__builtin__', 'ord': <built-in function ord>, 'super': <type 'super'>, '_': None, 'TypeError': <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, 'license': See http://www.python.org/2.7/license.html, 'KeyboardInterrupt': <type 'exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt'>, 'UserWarning': <type 'exceptions.UserWarning'>, 'filter': <built-in function filter>, 'range': <built-in function range>, 'staticmethod': <type 'staticmethod'>, 'SystemError': <type 'exceptions.SystemError'>, 'BaseException': <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>, 'pow': <built-in function pow>, 'RuntimeError': <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>, 'float': <type 'float'>, 'MemoryError': <type 'exceptions.MemoryError'>, 'StopIteration': <type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>, 'globals': <built-in function globals>, 'divmod': <built-in function divmod>, 'enumerate': <type 'enumerate'>, 'apply': <built-in function apply>, 'LookupError': <type 'exceptions.LookupError'>, 'open': <built-in function open>, 'quit': Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit, 'basestring': <type 'basestring'>, 'UnicodeError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeError'>, 'zip': <built-in function zip>, 'hex': <built-in function hex>, 'long': <type 'long'>, 'next': <built-in function next>, 'ImportError': <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, 'chr': <built-in function chr>, 'xrange': <type 'xrange'>, 'type': <type 'type'>, '__doc__': "Built-in functions, exceptions, and other objects.\n\nNoteworthy: None is the `nil' object; Ellipsis represents `...' in slices.", 'Exception': <type 'exceptions.Exception'>, 'tuple': <type 'tuple'>, 'UnicodeTranslateError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeTranslateError'>, 'reversed': <type 'reversed'>, 'UnicodeEncodeError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, 'IOError': <type 'exceptions.IOError'>, 'hasattr': <built-in function hasattr>, 'delattr': <built-in function delattr>, 'setattr': <built-in function setattr>, 'raw_input': <built-in function raw_input>, 'SyntaxWarning': <type 'exceptions.SyntaxWarning'>, 'compile': <built-in function compile>, 'ArithmeticError': <type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>, 'str': <type 'str'>, 'property': <type 'property'>, 'GeneratorExit': <type 'exceptions.GeneratorExit'>, 'int': <type 'int'>, '__import__': <built-in function __import__>, 'KeyError': <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, 'coerce': <built-in function coerce>, 'PendingDeprecationWarning': <type 'exceptions.PendingDeprecationWarning'>, 'file': <type 'file'>, 'EnvironmentError': <type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>, 'unichr': <built-in function unichr>, 'id': <built-in function id>, 'OSError': <type 'exceptions.OSError'>, 'DeprecationWarning': <type 'exceptions.DeprecationWarning'>, 'min': <built-in function min>, 'UnicodeWarning': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeWarning'>, 'execfile': <built-in function execfile>, 'any': <built-in function any>, 'complex': <type 'complex'>, 'bool': <type 'bool'>, 'ValueError': <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, 'NotImplemented': NotImplemented, 'map': <built-in function map>, 'buffer': <type 'buffer'>, 'max': <built-in function max>, 'object': <type 'object'>, 'TabError': <type 'exceptions.TabError'>, 'callable': <built-in function callable>, 'ZeroDivisionError': <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>, 'eval': <built-in function eval>, '__debug__': True, 'IndentationError': <type 'exceptions.IndentationError'>, 'AssertionError': <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>, 'classmethod': <type 'classmethod'>, 'UnboundLocalError': <type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'>, 'NotImplementedError': <type 'exceptions.NotImplementedError'>, 'AttributeError': <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, 'OverflowError': <type 'exceptions.OverflowError'>}
```

or you can simply blow up the interpreter by creating a broken code object. See [*Eval really is dangerous*](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

If all you want to do is load Python literal syntax (lists, tuples, dictionaries, strings, numbers, etc.) then you want to use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), specifically designed to be safe.

Comment: Maybe you want to mention `ast.literal_eval` and  link to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710247/python-3-are-there-any-known-security-holes-in-ast-literal-evalnode-or-string ? It seems like a likely follow-up question...

Comment: @NichtJens: added a mention; I don't think that question needs linking, the documentation is enough: *Safely evaluate ...*

Comment: Yes, great! You are actually simply answering that follow-up question already here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, this is a perfectly valid statement.

```
True = False
>>> print True
False
```

Try to do it with `None` though, and..

`SyntaxError: cannot assign to None`

Can kind of make your head spin. I'm not sure, but I suspect that `True` is a builtin and `None` is actually a *constant*. You can *change* `True` to a different value, but you can't change `None`.

Comment: No, True and False are the built-ins and can be masked.

Comment: So they're all built in? What's the difference then? EDIT: Ah, I see, `None` is a keyword too.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's technically a keyword either (at least not in python2.x):  `import keyword; print keyword.iskeyword('None')`

Comment: @mgilson: it isn't. It is a 'constant', so the compiler simply inserts the reference.

Comment: Well, I learned something at least...

I updated my answer to be as close to reality as possible.