# Can't calculate two values replacing certain sign

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, str-replace

How can I add two values replacing `/` between them? I tried with `item.replace("/","+")` but it only places the `+` sign replacing `/` and does nothing else. For example If i try the logic on `2/1.5` and `-3/-4.5`, I get `2+1.5` and `-3+-4.5`.

> My intention here is to add the two values replacing `/` between them and divide it into 2 so that the result becomes `1.875` and `-3.75` respectively if I try the logic on (`2/1.5` and `-3/-4.5`).

This is my try so far:

```
for item in ['2/1.5','-3/-4.5']:
    print(item.replace("/","+"))
```

What I'm having now:

```
2+1.5
-3+-4.5
```

Expected output (adding the two values replacing `/` with `+` and then divide result by two):

```
1.75
-3.75
```

Comment: Thee are strings, and you would have to compile and execute at runtime.  It would probably be better to extract the operator, convert the numeric strings to objects of the correct type, then add or divide them.

Comment: 2+1.5 is 3.5 not 1.875

Comment: Dive that into 2. I have mentioned it in my post @Agile_Eagle.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle The OP sad 2+1.5 will be divide 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `/` is only a separator, you don't really need to replace it with `+`, but use it with `split`, and then sum up the parts:

```
for item in ['2/1.5', '-3/-4.5']:
    result = sum(map(float, item.split('/'))) / 2
    print(result)
```

or in a more generalized form:

```
from statistics import mean

for item in ['2/1.5', '-3/-4.5']:
    result = mean(map(float, item.split('/')))
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using eval like this:

```
for item in ['2/1.5','-3/-4.5']:
    print((eval(item.replace("/","+")))/2)
```

Comment: Did you downvote me, yeah i don't know if `literal_eval` is good, that'a true

Comment: I realized for here `literal_eval` is safe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710247/python-3-are-there-any-known-security-holes-in-ast-literal-evalnode-or-string

Comment: `eval` is almost always the worst idea.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not that different from others, except I don't understand why everyone is using lists.  A list is not required here because it won't be altered, a `tuple` is fine and more efficient:

```
for item in '2/1.5','-3/-4.5':            # Don't need a list here
    num1, num2 = item.split('/')
    print((float(num1) + float(num2)) / 2)
```

Comment: I suppose, the OP used the list only as an example.

Answer (score 1):

A further elaboration of @daniel's answer:

```
[sum(map(float, item.split('/'))) / 2 for item in ('2/1.5','-3/-4.5')]
```

Result:

```
[1.75, -3.75]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from ast import literal_eval

l = ['2/1.5','-3/-4.5']
print([literal_eval(i.replace('/','+'))/2 for i in l])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this(by splitting the strings into two floats):

```
for item in ['2/1.5','-3/-4.5']:
    itemArray = item.split("/")
    itemResult = float(itemArray[0]) + float(itemArray[1])
    print(itemResult/2)
```

Comment: I edited your question because the OP wanted the result to be divided by 2

Comment: I edited your question because you are using (correctly) floats not integers.