# Python removing nested unicode 'u' sign from string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `unicode` object which should represent a `json` but it contains the unicode `u` in it as part of the string value e.g. `u'{u\'name\':u\'my_name\'}'`

My goal is to be able to load this into a `json` object. Just using `json.loads` fails. I know this happens because of the `u` inside the `string` which are not part of an acceptable `json` format.

I, then, tired sanitizing the `string` using `replace("u\'", "'")`, `encode('ascii', 'ignore')` and other methods without success.

What finally worked was using `ast.literal_eval` but I'm worried about using it. I found a few sources online claiming its [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7689085/4890123). But, I also found other sources claiming it's bad practice and one should avoid it.

Are there other methods I'm missing?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` *is* safe.

Comment: @dawg thanks for the quick response. Is it preferable to try and replace the `u` values etc.? Does `ast.literal_eval` have any negative downsides to it?

Comment: *Does ast.literal_eval have any negative downsides to it?* No, not really. If it works for your data (other than the example here) - use it.

Comment: Thanks for the assist @dawg

Comment: @GuyGrin, I have updated my answer with 1 more method. Please check, it as it allows you to use **json** module. Note that the **JSON** (JavaScript Object Notation) suggests `"` (double quotes) to surround keys and strings. And this is a reason for `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`. I have also suggested **Unsafe** way, just ignore that if you wish. You will need to find a way in case if your data string contains `u` as part of original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unicode string is the result of `unicode` being called on a dictionary.

```
>>> d = {u'name': u'myname'}
>>> u = unicode(d) 
>>> u  
u"{u'name': u'myname'}"
```

If you control the code that's doing this, the best fix is to change it to call `json.dumps` instead.

```
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"name": "myname"}'
```

If you don't control the creation of this object, you'll need to use `ast.literal_eval` to create the dictionary, as the unicode string is not valid json.

```
>>> json.loads(u)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)


>>> ast.literal_eval(u)
{u'name': u'myname'}
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) confirm that ast.literal_eval is safe:

> can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources

You *could* use `eval` instead, but as you don't control the creation of the object you cannot be certain that it has not been crafted by a malicious user, to cause damage to your system.