# Loading unicode json/serialized dictionary fails due to unicode error

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm given some input that I must parse and convert to a `Dict`. I don't control how the input is generated.

An example input is `u'{u\'my_key\': u\'AB\\N\'}'`. Notice the this should represent a serialized dictionary.

Parsing this dictionary string fails using a variety of methods. Using `json.loads` fails due to the [structure of the string being malformed due to the nested `u`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063796/python-removing-nested-unicode-u-sign-from-string). Using `ast.literal_eval` fails with a `(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: malformed \N character escape` error.

I need to somehow sanitize the input so the `\N` won't be considered an `ascii` character when parsed with `ast`. Doing a simple `replace('\\', '\\\\')` seems error prone and probably has many edge cases.

Alternatively, I need a way to remove the `u` from the nested string so `json.loads` would work.

Thanks

Comment: That's not JSON but a Python 2 dictionary representation. It is not intended to be a data exchange format.

Comment: "Parsing this json fails using a variety of methods" - because it _isn't_ json, it's just the result of calling `unicode` on a dictionary.  I know this isn't very helpful, but the solution here is to get whoever or whatever is sending you this garbage to fix their data.

Comment: Thank you both for trying to help. I'll edit the post to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Handling this kind of input is not easy. In fact the only solution I have been able to find is this one:

```
input_data = u'{u\'my_key\': u\'AB\\N\'}'

i = input_data\
    .replace('\'', '"')\
    .replace('u', '')\
    .replace('\\', '\\\\')

data = json.loads(i)
print(type(data))
# <type 'dict'>
```

It may solves your specific example, however I don't encourage to use it in your project.

As @snakecharmerb said, I would also suggest to enforce some kind of policy on the inputs and validate the json string before sending it, using something like [this](https://jsonlint.com/) for instance.