# python solve equation inside string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code

```
ecuation=("95502+45806-85773-659740")
answer = sum(int(x) for x in ecuation if x.isdigit())
print(answer)
```

Which prints this as answer

```
105
```

This is not correct, the idea is to get the ecuation from a web page (I already have that part working) and solve it.

**note:** The ecuation will always change but it will always be adding and substracting numbers.

Comment: how about `eval()`
Be careful though if the equations are from user input this could be a security issue, because harmful code could get run this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is this calculation:

```
9+5+5+0+2+4+5+8+0+6+8+5+7+7+3+6+5+9+7+4+0=105
```

What you want to do is break apart the string and add/subtract those numbers. This can be shortcut by using eval() (more [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)), as suggested by Vitor, or with ast.literal_eval (more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)), as suggested by rassar.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the `eval` function:

```
>>> ecuation=("95502+45806-85773-659740")
>>> eval(ecuation)
-604205
```

However, you need to be [very careful](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) while using this. A [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710247/python-3-are-there-any-known-security-holes-in-ast-literal-evalnode-or-string) way is:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(ecuation)
-604205
```

Comment: Good idea to advise using literal_eval

Comment: literal_eval only works with additions. Not with multiplications or divisions. But good trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ecuation=("95502+45806-85773-659740")
answer = eval(ecuation)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re`:

```
import re

ecuation= "95502+45806-85773-659740"

s = sum(int(g) for g in re.findall(r'((?:\+|-)?\d+)', ecuation))
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
-604205
```

Comment: Not sure if this is important, but this will not work for decimals.