# Split string only after double quotes in python

Tags: python, split

I have a string like this here:

```
"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"
```

And yes **the double quotes are within** this string.

Now I want to split this string into several parts with `mystring.split(",")`
What I got is this

```
"BLAX"

"BLAY"

"BLAZ

BLUBB"

"BLAP"
```

But what I want is this:

```
"BLAX"

"BLAY"

"BLAZ, BLUBB"

"BLAP"
```

How can I achieve this and as well I want to keep the double quotes? I need this because I work with toml files.

Solution:
Thanks @Giacomo Alzetta

I used the split command with the regular expression. Thanks also for explaining this!

Comment: split at `", ` (yes, one double quote there, or even with both: `", "`, so that `something, something` doesn't get split`) and then add a missing double quotes in a list comprehension

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<="),', '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"')
['"BLAX"', ' "BLAY"', ' "BLAZ, BLUBB"', ' "BLAP"']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and the `re.split` function:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?<="),', '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"')
['"BLAX"', ' "BLAY"', ' "BLAZ, BLUBB"', ' "BLAP"']
```

`(?<=")` means *must be preceded by `"`* but the `"` is not included in the actual match so only the `,` is used to actually do the splitting.

You could split by `",` but then you'd have to fix up the parts where the `"` is now missing:

```
>>> '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"'.split('",')
['"BLAX', ' "BLAY', ' "BLAZ, BLUBB', ' "BLAP"']
>>> [el + ('' if el.endswith('"') else '"') for el in '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"'.split('",')]
['"BLAX"', ' "BLAY"', ' "BLAZ, BLUBB"', ' "BLAP"']
```

Comment: But you have a single quote around the items, `' " XX " ' ` .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` and then add `'"'` manually:

```
s = '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"'

from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval('(' + s + ')')

for d in data:
    print('"{}"'.format(d))
```

Prints:

```
"BLAX"
"BLAY"
"BLAZ, BLUBB"
"BLAP"
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is not safe. You should generally avoid it.

Comment: Withdrawn. You are right - there is even a [question about safety of `ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710247/python-3-are-there-any-known-security-holes-in-ast-literal-evalnode-or-string).

Comment: Your answer would fail if a `"` is missing somewhere or if the input contains something like `"hello" 5`. Maybe all OP inputs are valid python syntax but they did not state that, they only said they don't want to split on a comma that is not after a `"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

s = '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"' 
r = csv.reader(s, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
res = [j for i in r for j in i if j.strip()] 
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['BLAX', 'BLAY', 'BLAZ, BLUBB', 'BLAP']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split by `"` then remove the unwanted leftovers, and rewrap everything in quotes, with a simple list-comp.

```py
string = '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"'

parts = ['"{}"'.format(s) for s in string.split('"') if s not in ('', ', ')]

for p in parts:
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
"BLAX"
"BLAY"
"BLAZ, BLUBB"
"BLAP"
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, you can split at more than a single separator. A comma gets both a one in quotes and outside, but we can do split at `",` (added a space so that we don't have to strip it ;) )

Then we add the missing quotations:

```
original = '"BLAX", "BLAY", "BLAZ, BLUBB", "BLAP"'
[s if s.endswith('"') else s+'"' for s in original.split('", ')]
```

Output: `['"BLAX"', '"BLAY"', '"BLAZ, BLUBB"', '"BLAP"']`

This approach doesn't use regexes, so it's faster. You also don't need to play with what regexes are correct for your case (I generally like regexes, but I like smart splitting and operations more).

Answer (score 0):

You may `replace` and `split`

```
s.replace('", ', '"|').split('|')

Out[672]: ['"BLAX"', ' "BLAY"', ' "BLAZ, BLUBB"', ' "BLAP"']
```

Comment: Change first argument to `'", '` (add space) so that output doesn't have unnecessary spaces. :)

Comment: @h4z3; Thanks. I just do it right off the bat and didn't notice the added space. +1