# Convert string list (with spaces instead of commas) into a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following string:

```
'[[ 0.03694573  0.01084746  0.01306414  0.00499198  0.00307188]\r\n [ 0.03780498  0.02610241  0.00967986  0.02228694 -0.01153102]\r\n [ 0.03837708  0.02111896  0.01370878 -0.00136839  0.01906253]\r\n [ 0.03490672 -0.02791057  0.08824896 -0.01991765  0.01964361]\r\n [ 0.0811892   0.28361901  0.21539196 -0.00259571  0.28737829]\r\n [ 0.20022041  0.16184418  0.25939959  0.00546446  0.36415219]\r\n [ 0.22920615  0.27439767  0.36991198  0.00624375  0.39911759]]'
```

As you can see, it comprises of a list of lists. However, each element within the lists are separated by tabs and not commas, and therefore `ast.literal_eval()` does not work. Does anyone have any ideas how best to convert this into a list of lists?

BJR
​

Comment: how about `.split`?

Comment: Why do you have it in that format? If you're reading it from a file, can you not just store the numbers in a 2D grid

Comment: Replace the tabs with commas first: `s.replace("\t", ",")`

Comment: The numbers are the raw Permutation Importance indices stored from SciKit Learn. I will try and alter how they are saved, but for now I was just interested how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `re.sub`:

```
import re
literal_eval(','.join(re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(\s+)(?=-?\d)', ',', s).splitlines()))

[[0.03694573, 0.01084746, 0.01306414, 0.00499198, 0.00307188],
 [0.03780498, 0.02610241, 0.00967986, 0.02228694, -0.01153102],
 [0.03837708, 0.02111896, 0.01370878, -0.00136839, 0.01906253],
 [0.03490672, -0.02791057, 0.08824896, -0.01991765, 0.01964361],
 [0.0811892, 0.28361901, 0.21539196, -0.00259571, 0.28737829],
 [0.20022041, 0.16184418, 0.25939959, 0.00546446, 0.36415219],
 [0.22920615, 0.27439767, 0.36991198, 0.00624375, 0.39911759]]
```

Comment: That works well. Now I just need to decode what all that regex means.

Comment: Meaning: Replace every block of whitespace that is preceded by a digit and not followed by either a "-" or a digit with one ",".

Answer (score 1):

Modify the string until it can be interpreted by [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Basically this means adding a "," where needed.

If your string is called `data`:

```
import ast
data = data.replace('  ', ',').replace('\r\n ', ',')
result = ast.literal_eval(dat2)
```

Now `result` will contain your list of lists.

I'm not sure if you have spaces or tabs there. If you have tabs you'll have to replace `'  '` by `'\t\t'`.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is dubbed **dangerous**.

Comment: @amirouche Do you confuse `eval` and `literal_eval`? Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710247/python-3-are-there-any-known-security-holes-in-ast-literal-evalnode-or-string.

Comment: Sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough idea. Can be made smaller.

```
input = '[[ 0.03694573  0.01084746  0.01306414  0.00499198  0.00307188]\r\n [ 0.03780498  0.02610241  0.00967986  0.02228694 -0.01153102]\r\n [ 0.03837708  0.02111896  0.01370878 -0.00136839  0.01906253]\r\n [ 0.03490672 -0.02791057  0.08824896 -0.01991765  0.01964361]\r\n [ 0.0811892   0.28361901  0.21539196 -0.00259571  0.28737829]\r\n [ 0.20022041  0.16184418  0.25939959  0.00546446  0.36415219]\r\n [ 0.22920615  0.27439767  0.36991198  0.00624375  0.39911759]]'

input = input.replace('\r\n', ',')

array_of_arrays = input.split(',')
array_of_strings = []
for arr in array_of_arrays:
     _arr = arr.replace('[', '')
     _arr = _arr.replace(']', '')
     array_of_strings.append(_arr)
result = []
for arr in array_of_strings:
     num_strings = arr.split()
     num_arr = [float(x) for x in num_strings]
     result.append(num_arr)

print(result)
```