# How to get a list with dict entries from text file?

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I saved a list with dict entries to a txt file.

When I try to read it back into python with

```
data = open("my_saved_data.txt","r")
```

I just get a huge string which looks like this:

```
[{key1:"value",key2:"value"},{key1:"value",key2:"value"},{key1:"value",key2:"value"}]
```

What's an easy way to get this back in the original format?

Comment: If you're trying to save dictionary data, I would suggest using the `json` module. Do you have control over the format that you're saving the dictionary in?

Comment: You _could_ use `ast.literal_eval` as well. But JSON is likely a better choice (parsers for it written in many programming languages).

Comment: You can use json package, which supports json object Serializing and Deserializing

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I would rather not use `literal_eval` on the contents of a file. You can easily inject malicious code in the file.

Comment: `eval()` is the unsafe one, [`literal_eval()` is (probably) fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710247/python-3-are-there-any-known-security-holes-in-ast-literal-evalnode-or-string).

Comment: `data = open("my_saved_data.txt","r")` will **not** get you a string because afterwards `data` will simply be an open file object of some kind (i.e. not the contents of the file).

Comment: If you saved the list to the file using `json.dump()`, you would be able to read it back into its original format via `json.load()`. I think not saving it properly is the root cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is "Convert a String to JSON", but the type of your file content is not JSON, because the key in JSON should be enclosed in double quotes.

The correct content should like this:

```
[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}]
```

then we can convert it to original format:

```py
with open("my_saved_data.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read()

print(data)
# '[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}]'

import json
json.loads(data)
#[{'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value'},
# {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value'},
# {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value'}]
```

Please make sure whether your key in str is enclosed or not, if not, we can make it enclosed by:

```
with open("my_saved_data.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read()

data.replace('key1','"key1"').replace('key2','"key2"')
```