# optimise python regex search

Tags: python, regex, string, optimization, tree

**Code**

```
def search(self, arg1, arg2):
    global ipv4_regex, type_regex

    if isinstance(arg2, type_regex):
        text = re.search(arg2, arg1)
        if text:
            p = text.group()
            return len(p)
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        if arg2 in arg1:
            return len(arg2)
        else:
            return 0
```

I have a python script where, to serve one request, this function gets recomputed around 452900 times(found this value by doing profiling of code using pprofile), to give the output.

**Some notes about function:**

```
arg1 = string
arg2 = ith string/regex
```

Basically, `arg2` is an `ith` instance of a long list of regex/strings that needs to be matched against `arg1` (arg1 remains constant for one request) inorder to find matching length.

I came up with this function, but time & CPU consumption is becoming bottleneck for me. Because of many search operations, CPU goes very high soon.

**What ideas I thought till now**

1. Use dictionary comprehension instead of `if-else` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442724/how-to-use-if-else-in-a-dictionary-comprehension)
2. Use some kind of Tree based search, the way we do for strings.

both these ideas are simple ideas as of now, I am not able to bring them into action.

I have no control over regexes in arg2, so regex optimization wouldn't help here.

Please suggest, I am looking for ideas as to how can i optimize this function?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is this used for?

Comment: If you need to run half a million regexes on a string, and you're just getting compiled regex objects and have no control over what they are, I don't see how anything you can do is likely to make a difference. Presumably it's that `re.search` that accounts for 95%+ of the time, right? I assume you don't want to try writing your own regex library that can parse Python regex objects and merge them into a single machine (and do it all quickly enough that the cost doesn't swamp the benefit). So… you can probably parallelize it if you've got spare cores, but what else is even conceivable?