# How to unlist a list in a dictionary in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list like this:

```
list = [{'item1': value1,
         'item2': [{'tinyitem21': tinyvalue21, 'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22}]},
        {'item3': [{'tinyitem31': tinyvalue31, 'tinyitem32': tinyvalue32}],
         'item4': value4}]
```

I want to have a list like this:

```
list = [{'item1': value1,
         'item2': {'tinyitem21': tinyvalue21, 'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22}},
        {'item3': {'tinyitem31': tinyvalue31, 'tinyitem32': tinyvalue32},
         'item4': value4}]
```

I have written the code below to try to solve this problem but it doesn't work:

```
for item in list:
    for smallitem, smallvalue in item:
        if type(smallvalue)=='list':
            new_dict= {}
            for tinyitem in smallvalue:
                name = tinyitem.pop('name')
                new_dict[name] = tinyitem
            smallvalue=new_dict
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: BRO, Salute for question title though :V

Comment: @Eternal: it took me 5 minutes to type the question content but 10 minutes to think of the question title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this function (note that the list is modified inplace):

**Code:**

```
def f(l):
    for d in l:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, list):
                d[k] = v[0]
    return l
```

**Output:**

```
>>> f(lst)
[{'item1': value1,
  'item2': {'tinyitem21': tinyvalue21, 'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22}},
 {'item3': {'tinyitem31': tinyvalue31, 'tinyitem32': tinyvalue32},
  'item4': value4}]
```

**You could also use a list/dict comprehension:**

```
>>> [{k: v[0] if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in d.items()} for d in lst]
[{'item1': value1,
  'item2': {'tinyitem21': tinyvalue21, 'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22}},
 {'item3': {'tinyitem31': tinyvalue31, 'tinyitem32': tinyvalue32},
  'item4': value4}]
```

**If you have more nested lists/dicts than one level, you could use this recursive function:**

```
def f(lst):
    return [recursive_function(d) for d in lst] 

def recursive_function(d):
    rv = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            v = v[0]
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                v = recursive_function(v)
        rv[k] = v
    return rv
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> lst = [{'item1': value1,
            'item2': [{'tinyitem21': [{'tinyitem21': tinyvalue21,
                                       'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22}],
                       'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22}]},
           {'item3': [{'tinyitem31': tinyvalue31, 'tinyitem32': tinyvalue32}],
            'item4': value4}]
>>> f(lst)
[{'item1': 'value1',
  'item2': {'tinyitem21': {'tinyitem21': tinyvalue21,
                           'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22},
            'tinyitem22': tinyvalue22}},
 {'item3': {'tinyitem31': tinyvalue31, 'tinyitem32': tinyvalue32},
  'item4': value'}]
```

Comment: The function gives `TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable` the second time I use. Could you please let me know why is that the case. Can the function be used only once in a script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for first level nested conversion.

```
import json

input_list = [{'item1':"value",'item2':[{'tinyitem21':'tinyvalue21','tinyitem22':'tinyvalue22'}]},{'item3':[{'tinyitem31':'tinyvalue31','tinyitem32':'tinyvalue32'}],'item4':'value4'}]

for index, j in enumerate(range(len(input_list))):
    for key, value in input_list[index].items():
        if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1:  # Checking for single dictionary as multiple values of dict cannot considered as json
            input_list[index][key] = value[0]

print(json.dumps(input_list, indent=3))
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      "item1": "value",
      "item2": {
         "tinyitem21": "tinyvalue21",
         "tinyitem22": "tinyvalue22"
      }
   },
   {
      "item3": {
         "tinyitem31": "tinyvalue31",
         "tinyitem32": "tinyvalue32"
      },
      "item4": "value4"
   }
]
```

And let say if the value at **`item2` at index 0 has more than one dict** then it should be considered as string value as shown in below output

```
import json

input_list = [{'item1':"value",'item2':[{'tinyitem21':'tinyvalue21','tinyitem22':'tinyvalue22'},{'tinyitem23':'tinyvalue21','tinyitem24':'tinyvalue22'}]},{'item3':[{'tinyitem31':'tinyvalue31','tinyitem32':'tinyvalue32'}],'item4':'value4'}]


for index, j in enumerate(range(len(input_list))):
    for key, value in input_list[index].items():
        if isinstance(value, list):  # without checking len of list
            input_list[index][key] = ','.join(map(str, value))  # string value be assigned instead of dictionary

print(json.dumps(input_list, indent=3))
```

Output will be string instead of dict but if you notice `item3` being single dict of list but still being assinged as str.

```
[
   {
      "item1": "value",
      "item2": "{'tinyitem21': 'tinyvalue21', 'tinyitem22': 'tinyvalue22'},{'tinyitem23': 'tinyvalue21', 'tinyitem24': 'tinyvalue22'}"
   },
   {
      "item3": "{'tinyitem31': 'tinyvalue31', 'tinyitem32': 'tinyvalue32'}",
      "item4": "value4"
   }
]
```

To handle both list with one/many dict with more readability.

```
for index, j in enumerate(range(len(input_list))):
    for key, value in input_list[index].items():
        if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1:  # Checking for single dictionary as multiple values of dict cannot considered as json
            input_list[index][key] = value[0]
        if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 1:  # for list of dict with more than one 
            input_list[index][key] = ','.join(map(str, value))  # string value be assigned instead of dictionary
```

**if you want to use comprehensive way** mentioned by CDJB you need to add one more condition to it because if in case of list with size more than 1 it will silently ignore second index.

```
[{k: v[0] if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in d.items()} for d in input_list]
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      "item1": "value",
      "item2": "{'tinyitem21': 'tinyvalue21', 'tinyitem22': 'tinyvalue22'},{'tinyitem23': 'tinyvalue21', 'tinyitem24': 'tinyvalue22'}"
   },
   {
      "item3": {
         "tinyitem31": "tinyvalue31",
         "tinyitem32": "tinyvalue32"
      },
      "item4": "value4"
   }
]
```

Comment: CDJB's comprehensive listing code is only snippet I have copied. Rest all is my effort. Though I have copied that snippet, I have updated on top of his code(i.e, added fix ` len(v) == 1`) but still I have made sure to mention his name over there. So lets stop judging and keep coding Abhi.

Answer (score 0):

One liner in Python:

```
lt = [{'item1':'value1', 'item2':[{'tinyitem21':'tinyvalue21','tinyitem22':'tinyvalue22'}]}, {'item3':[{'tinyitem31':'tinyvalue31','tinyitem32':'tinyvalue32'}], 'item4': 'value4'}]

li = [{i:(j[0] if isinstance(j, list) and len(j) > 0 else j) for i,j in m.items()} for m in lt]

print(li)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'item1': 'value1', 'item2': {'tinyitem21': 'tinyvalue21', 'tinyitem22': 'tinyvalue22'}}, {'item3': {'tinyitem31': 'tinyvalue31', 'tinyitem32': 'tinyvalue32'}, 'item4': 'value4'}]
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442724/how-to-use-if-else-in-a-dictionary-comprehension) for "How to use if/else in a dictionary comprehension?".