# How to filter dictionary using value of another dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Case 1: I wanna filter Dict1 using the value of Dict2, Ex : filter value >1 using value of dict2

```
 Dict1={'saya': 0.1823215567939546,
     'menolak': 0.6931471805599453,
     'omnibus': -0.15415067982725836,
     'law': -0.15415067982725836,
     'dan': 1.0986122886681098,
     'tetap': 1.0986122886681098,
     'di': 1.0986122886681098,
     'sekolah': 1.0986122886681098,
     'diperintahkan': 1.0986122886681098,
     'untuk': 1.0986122886681098,
     'tidak': 1.0986122886681098,
     'layak': 1.0986122886681098,
     'meningkatkan': 1.0986122886681098,
     'kesejahteraan': 1.0986122886681098,
     'setuju': 0.6931471805599453,
     'diterapkan': 0.6931471805599453}

Dict2={'saya': 1,
 'menolak': 2,
 'omnibus': 3,
 'law': 1,
 'dan': 0.5,
 'tetap': 0.5,
 'di': 1,
 'sekolah': 2,
 'diperintahkan': 3,
 'untuk': 4,
 'tidak': 5,
 'layak': 1.0986122886681098,
 'meningkatkan': 6,
 'kesejahteraan': 5,
 'setuju': 8,
 'diterapkan': 2}
```

The result that i hope:

```
Result={
         'menolak': 0.6931471805599453,
         'omnibus': -0.15415067982725836,
         'sekolah': 1.0986122886681098,
         'diperintahkan': 1.0986122886681098,
         'untuk': 1.0986122886681098,
         'tidak': 1.0986122886681098,
         'meningkatkan': 1.0986122886681098,
         'kesejahteraan': 1.0986122886681098,
         'setuju': 0.6931471805599453,
         'diterapkan': 0.6931471805599453 }
```

Case 2: I wanna filter Dict1 using the value of Dict2, Ex : filter the 5 best value using value of dict2

The result that i hope:

```
Dict2={
 'untuk': 1.0986122886681098,
 'tidak': 1.0986122886681098,
 'meningkatkan': 1.0986122886681098,
 'kesejahteraan': 1.0986122886681098,
 'setuju': 0.6931471805599453,
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problem did you run into? Currently, your question looks very much like you're asking SO to write your code for you?

Comment: [create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)

Comment: [how-can-i-use-if-else-in-a-dictionary-comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442724/how-can-i-use-if-else-in-a-dictionary-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve using the following -

1st Result:

```
Result_1 = {key: value for key, value in Dict1.items() if Dict2.get(key, 0) > 1}

{'menolak': 0.6931471805599453,
'omnibus': -0.15415067982725836,
'sekolah': 1.0986122886681098,
'diperintahkan': 1.0986122886681098,
'untuk': 1.0986122886681098,
'tidak': 1.0986122886681098,
'layak': 1.0986122886681098,
'meningkatkan': 1.0986122886681098,
'kesejahteraan': 1.0986122886681098,
'setuju': 0.6931471805599453,
'diterapkan': 0.6931471805599453}
```

2nd Result:

```
 Result_2 = {k: Dict1[k] for k in sorted(Dict2.keys(), key = lambda x: Dict2[x], reverse = True)[:5] if k in Dict1}

{'setuju': 0.6931471805599453,
 'meningkatkan': 1.0986122886681098,
 'tidak': 1.0986122886681098,
 'kesejahteraan': 1.0986122886681098,
 'untuk': 1.0986122886681098}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
result = {}

for key1, value1 in Dict1.items():
    for key2, value2 in Dict2.items():
        if Dict2[key2] > 1:
            result[key1] = Dict1[key1]
```