# .get() only if value is not None

Tags: python

I want to iterate over a dict and do some calculations with the data. But I don't want NoneType data, else I get an error. So I do this:

```
sum_value = 0 if values.get("sum", 0) is None else values.get("sum", 0)
```

Isn't there a better way to do this in Python?

Comment: `values.get("sum", 0)` already returns 0 if `values["sum"]` doesn't exist. Or do you mean that `values["sum"]` itself can be `None`?

Comment: yes, values["sum"] itself can be None

Comment: The best way would be to prevent that `values["sum"]` can be `None`.

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: This behaviour reminds me of numerical aggregates in django where the aggregate value is `None` for empty querysets.

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
sum_value = values.get("sum") or 0
```

The `or` will pick the second operand for all false (falsy) first operands which includes `None`, but excludes all non-zero numbers.

Comment: what does the or?

Comment: In general, both `and` and `or` evaluate to the first operand that determines the outcome wrt to truthiness. For `and` that is the first falsy operand (or the last one overall if there is no truthy one), for `or` it is the first truthy operand (or the last one overall).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that values.get("sum", 0) is already sufficient, as the 0 is the default value returned if the dictionary does not contain anything under the specified key.

Comment: And if the value of the key is NoneType?

Comment: Though, when I do 'round(sum_value, 2)' I get an TypeError: type NoneType doesn't define __round__ method

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an ordinary `if` statement to update the value, captured using an assignment statement in Python 3.8 or later

```
if (sum_value := values.get("sum", 0)) is None:
    sum_value = 0
```

or prior to the `if` statement in earlier versions of Python.

```
sum_value = values.get("sum", 0)
if sum_value is None:
    sum_value = 0
```

You can use the assignment expression in a conditional expression as well:

```
sum_value = 0 if (x:=values.get("sum", 0)) is None else x
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for a dictionary comprehension:

`{x:(y if y else 0) for x,y in r.items()}`

here's another good post on it

[How can I use if/else in a dictionary comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442724/how-can-i-use-if-else-in-a-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: `NoneType` is not an existing built-in name. Test `if y is None` instead, or do `x: y or 0`.

Comment: Even if it *were* a built-in name, comparing types for equality is frowned upon.

Comment: @chepner That's of course the next issue =) In particular for a type that only has a single instance, hence the hint to test for instance identity.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess I should have ran the code before posting :). Response edited. Why is it typically frowned upon to do a type comparison? Is that a general rule or specifically in this instance? @chepner

Comment: At the very least, it bypasses inheritance. For example, `type(True) == int` is false, but `True` is an `int`, in the sense that `bool` is a subclass of `int`. You rarely care about the *exact* type of a value.