# how to transform a loop for with if condition into comprehension dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, dictionary-comprehension

I'm not at ease with comprehension dictionaries
I would like to transform this loop into a dictionary comprehension.

Thanks for your help

```
dico={}
for key in ['good','very good','bad','very bad','not good not bad']:
  if key in['good','very good']:
    dico[key]='green'
  else:
    dico[key]='red'
print(dico)
```

Here is what's expected

```
{'good': 'green',
 'very good': 'green',
 'bad': 'red',
 'very bad': 'red',
 'not good not bad': 'red'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use if/else in a dictionary comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442724/how-can-i-use-if-else-in-a-dictionary-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you you're looking to this

```
dico = {key: ['red', 'green'] [key in ['good','very good']] for key in ['good','very good','bad','very bad','not good not bad']}
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but the version from @AbdulNiyasPM in the comment to the question might be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax

```
{k:'green' if k in ['good','very good'] else 'red' for k in ['good','very good','bad','very bad','not good not bad']}
```