# Why do int keys of a python dict turn into strings when using json.dumps?

Tags: python, json, serialization

According to [this conversion table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#py-to-json-table), Python ints get written as JSON numbers when serialized using the JSON module--as I would expect and desire.

I have a dictionary with an integer key and integer value:

```
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> type(d.items()[0][0])
<type 'int'>
>>> type(d.items()[0][1])
<type 'int'>
```

When I use the json module to serialize this to a JSON string, the value is written as a number, but the key is written as a string:

```
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"1": 2}'
```

This isn't the behavior I want, and it seems particularly broken since it breaks json.dumps/json.loads round-tripping:

```
>>> d == json.loads(json.dumps(d))
False
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way I can force the key to be written as a number?

Comment: JSON keys are *always* strings.

Comment: ...and JSON uses strings because they're byte-order independent.

Comment: If JSON is not *strictly* required, you could go for YAML using PyYAML instead : `d = {1:2, 3:4}; import yaml; yaml.safe_load(yaml.safe_dump(d)) == d` returns True. In general the 'inline' style of YAML looks like more flexible json (keys can be numbers, strings usually don't have to be quoted). I use `safe_load` here because normal `yaml.load` has features (construction of classes,etc) that it's hard to secure correctly; `safe_load|dump` restrict the set of supported input/outputs to primitive types (bool,int,float,string,list,set,dict) and so are safe to use on arbitrary inputs.

Comment: Unfortunately the round tripping does not hold with yaml.safe_dump because it converts strings of things looking like ints into ints. E.g. try it with d = {'1':'2'}

Comment: Bug for above round tripping issue: https://bitbucket.org/xi/pyyaml/issue/21

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's json module, converts int dictionary keys to strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450957/pythons-json-module-converts-int-dictionary-keys-to-strings)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The simple reason is that [JSON does not allow integer keys.](http://json.org/)

```
object
    {}
    { members } 
members
    pair
    pair , members
pair
    string : value  # Keys *must* be strings.
```

As to how to get around this limitation - you will first need to ensure that the receiving implementation can handle the technically-invalid JSON.  Then you can either replace all of the quote marks or use a custom serializer.

Comment: And unlike plain javascript. all keys should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, you can check keys for being convertable to integers again using:

```
def pythonify(json_data):
    for key, value in json_data.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = [ pythonify(item) if isinstance(item, dict) else item for item in value ]
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = pythonify(value)
        try:
            newkey = int(key)
            del json_data[key]
            key = newkey
        except TypeError:
            pass
        json_data[key] = value
    return json_data
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will recursively cast all string-keys to int-keys, if possible. If not possible the key-type will remain unchanged.

I adjusted [JLT's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4837077/jlt) example below slightly. With some of my huge nested dictionaries that code made the size of the dictionary change, ending with an exception. Anyhow, credit goes to JLT!

```
def pythonify(json_data):

    correctedDict = {}

    for key, value in json_data.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = [pythonify(item) if isinstance(item, dict) else item for item in value]
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = pythonify(value)
        try:
            key = int(key)
        except Exception as ex:
            pass
        correctedDict[key] = value

    return correctedDict
```