# The jsonpickle converts my dictionary keys from numbers to strings

Tags: python

I was trying to serialize my objects in a way that I could read them in the external form and found jsonpickle.   But it turns out that it converts my dictionary keys from integers to strings.

I noticed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450957/pythons-json-module-converts-int-dictionary-keys-to-strings) on the problem using just the JSON package but I was hoping that jsonpickle would fix the problem.   Are there any known workarounds?  Alternatively is there a better text-mode serialization format to use for Python?

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>>> a={}
>>> a[11]="eleventy"
>>> a[22]="twice that"
>>> a
{11: 'eleventy', 22: 'twice that'}
>>> import jsonpickle
>>> jstring=jsonpickle.encode(a)
>>> jstring
'{"22": "twice that", "11": "eleventy"}'
>>> b=jsonpickle.decode(jstring)
>>> b
{'22': 'twice that', '11': 'eleventy'}
>>>
```

***Update:*** For short term my work around is to have parallel save functions -- one to pickle and one to jsonpickle.   Since my objects are complex (circular references) I can't get away with something that can't handle that.   My original requirement was to have a format that I could read in a text editor so I could detect problems with the logic so as long as regular pickel is reliable (it is) than that will do me for now.   Someday I might want to have some other non-Python software eat this file so I would like to find a usable solution.   XML format?   The Python community doesn't seem to be that interested in serializing to XML.  At least I haven't found a package that works as easily as pickle/jsonpickle does.

Comment: How large is your data? For small ones, you could just use `repr`. (Larger ones work, too, it's just not pretty-printed so might be hard to read)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the JSON format (http://json.org/) requires all keys in an object (dict keys in python) to be strings.

Though not text based, MessagePack allows integer mapping keys:

```
>>> import msgpack
>>> type(msgpack.unpackb(msgpack.packb({12: 23})).keys()[0])
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 5):

In jsonpickle you can use the 'keys' argument to save keys without coercing them to string.

To encode, do:

```
jsonpickle.encode(your_object, keys=True)
```

and to decode:

```
jsonpickle.decode(the_encoded_object, keys=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `repr` for small things or `pprint` in general:

```
>>> a = {i: i for i in range(20)}
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
{0: 0,
 1: 1,
 2: 2,
 3: 3,
 4: 4,
 5: 5,
 6: 6,
 7: 7,
 8: 8,
 9: 9,
 10: 10,
 11: 11,
 12: 12,
 13: 13,
 14: 14,
 15: 15,
 16: 16,
 17: 17,
 18: 18,
 19: 19}
```

You can also give `pprint` a stream to write into:

```
with open('mydata.txt', 'w') as f:
    pprint.pprint(a, f)
```

And you can read that back like this:

```
import ast
with open('mydata.txt') as f:
    b = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Comment: That's interesting and I will look into it, but my object is too complex for that.   It has circular object references.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the JSON object definition from http://json.org. So basically all keys **MUST** be string, so your int key will be converted to string when converting object to JSON object. Nothing else.

You don't have to use jsonpickle if all you need is string representation.

```
>>> a={}
>>> a[11]="eleventy"
>>> a[22]="twice that"
>>> str(a)
"{11: 'eleventy', 22: 'twice that'}"
```