# How to convert Python dict to JSON when some keys are not strings?

Tags: python, json

The JSON equivalent of a Python dict is a JSON object. However its keys must be strings, that's a well-known limitation.

I need to support also boolean and numeric keys. I could make a simple Python value <--> JSON string one-to-one translation:

```
False <--> "bool:False"
42 <--> "int:42"
"Foo" <--> "str:Foo"
```

But I'd like to ask if there is some existing recommendation or some kind of standard for this. Simply anything that it is worth to be compatible with.

Comment: i think you can just omit bool:, int:, str: to make it simpler.

Comment: I suppose that you could do `bool(False)`, `int(42)` and use `eval`.

Comment: can you just do `{str(k): v for k, v in d.items()}`

Comment: For JSON, not that I know of. You could instead use msgpack or some other format that works the way you want.

Comment: Here's some discussion that you may find valuable http://stackoverflow.com/q/1450957/1916449

Comment: Or maybe `{'{}:{}'.format(type(k).__name__, str(k)): v for k, v in d.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON isn't able to do that and I don't know of any widely-used extensions of JSON that allow you to do this. You'd have to write the serializer and deserializer yourself, which probably wouldn't be that difficult if you subclass [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) and [`json.JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder).

If you're able to switch protocols, there are JSON-ish protocols that support non-string keys. [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/index.html) is one:

```
>>> import msgpack
>>> msgpack.loads(msgpack.dumps({'1': 12, False: 3, 2: 8}))
{False: 3, 2: 8, '1': 12}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.This time I need to make a change as small as possible to an existing system, so I must stay with JSON. +1 because I learned someting new.

Comment: "_I don't know of any widely-used extensions of JSON that allow you to do this_" is accepted as a direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This would achieve what you want:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {False: 'this data', 42: 'answer', 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> json.dumps({"%s:%s" % (type(k).__name__, k): v for k, v in data.items()})
'{"int:42": "answer", "str:foo": "bar", "bool:False": "this data"}'
```

You'd then have to de-serialize this, and it would only work for basic types.

Comment: Yes, something like this will do. However there are many possible variations. I just wanted to know, if some format is already in use or otherwise preferred. It looks like the answer is negative, but that's a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot issue standard JSON, why don't you just use `str` to serialize and [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) (standard package) to deserialize?

```
>>> d = {'a': 33, 23:(4,5), False: 10, 4: "foo"}
>>> a = str(d)   # convert the python structure to a string
>>> d2 = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> print(d2)  # evaluate the a literal to a python structure
{False: 10, 4: 'foo', 'a': 33, 23: (4, 5)}
>>> d2 == d   # are those the same before & after evaluation ?
True
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.This time I need to make a change as small as possible to an existing system, so I must stay with JSON.