# Pandas to_json turning index into string

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas `to_json` function for some reason is converting the index of the dataframe into strings. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3], "b" : [2,3,4]})
>>> df.to_json(orient = "index")
'{"0":{"a":1,"b":2},"1":{"a":2,"b":3},"2":{"a":3,"b":4}}'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(df.to_json(orient="index"))
{'2': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, '1': {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, '0': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `orient='records'` instead.

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Then

```
json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))
```

will give output as

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Keys in `json` cannot be `int`. Better it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1450957/2901002).

There is one possible solution - use parameter `split` in [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) if need store index values as `int`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3], "b" : [2,3,4]}, index=[100,200,300])
print (df)
     a  b
100  1  2
200  2  3
300  3  4

a = df.to_json(orient = "split")
print (a)
{"columns":["a","b"],"index":[100,200,300],"data":[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]}

print (pd.read_json(a, orient='split'))
     a  b
100  1  2
200  2  3
300  3  4
```

Comment: This gives me a `ValueError: Length of values (10) does not match length of index (2)`