# Read a JSON and convert the keys to int

Tags: python, json, dictionary

It is well known that `json` converts integer keys of a dict to string:

```
import json
print json.dumps({1: [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], 2: [3, 3, 3, 3]})
# {"1": [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], "2": [3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

What's the cleanest way to restore integer keys when loading it back?

```
d = json.loads('{"1": [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], "2": [3, 3, 3, 3]}')
print d
# {u'1': [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], u'2': [3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

I was thinking about:

```
d = {int(k): d[k] for k in d}
```

but is there a cleaner way to deal with dictionaries with integer keys with JSON / Python, not requiring keys conversion a posteriori?

Comment: Cleaner in what way? You could do `{int(k):v for k,v in d.items()}`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To avoid conversion, and have it directly loaded back as a dict with integer keys.

Comment: Well, since JSON requires string keys, you'll either have to write your own decoder (which is straightforward with the `json` library) or just convert, or chose an alternative serialization format.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hum, ok, I think this is the answer (if you want to post it).

Answer (score 17):

Use `object_hook` to define a custom function and perform operations:

```
import json

def keystoint(x):
    return {int(k): v for k, v in x.items()}

j = json.dumps({1: [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], 2: [3, 3, 3, 3]})
# {"1": [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], "2": [3, 3, 3, 3]}

print(json.loads(j, object_hook=keystoint))
# {1: [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], 2: [3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

> `object_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the
>   result of any object literal decoded (a dict). The return value
>   of `object_hook` will be used instead of the dict.

---

Or, you could also use `object_pairs_hook` that lets you iterate through pairs and saves the `.items()` call (Thanks @chepner):

```
import json

def keystoint(x):
    return {int(k): v for k, v in x}

j = json.dumps({1: [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], 2: [3, 3, 3, 3]})
# {"1": [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], "2": [3, 3, 3, 3]}

print(json.loads(j, object_pairs_hook=keystoint))
# {1: [2.5, 2.5, 2.5], 2: [3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

From docs:

> `object_pairs_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the
>   result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs.
>   The return value of `object_pairs_hook` will be used instead of
>   the dict.

Comment: `object_pairs_hook` is slightly simpler (saving a call to the `items` method), as it receives a list of key/value pairs instead of a dict. `loads(j, object_pairs_hook=lambda pairs: {int(k): v for k,v in pairs})`.

Comment: @chepner, nice point. Of course, if the size is larger, saving `.items()` call should matter.

Comment: The default decoder, at least, always builds a concrete list of key/value pairs in memory. `object_pairs_hook` short-circuits the normal process by operating directly on that list; otherwise, the list is first turned into a `dict`, which is either returned as-is or passed to `object_hook` (That is, given `pairs`, the decoder returns `object_pairs_hook(pairs)`, `dict(pairs)`, or `object_hook(dict(pairs))`.)

Comment: Doesn't work for recursive string keys.

Answer (score 5):

I also want to add another solution if you would have a nested dictionary.

---

I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113201/11953327) under another question which handles ordinary dictionaries and also **nested dictionaries** which gives error if you have non-integer keys in the second layers.

```
>>> import json
>>> json_data = '{"1": "one", "2": {"-3": "minus three", "4": "four"}}'
>>> py_dict = json.loads(json_data, object_hook=lambda d: {int(k) 
                         if k.lstrip('-').isdigit() else k: v for k, v in d.items()})
>>> py_dict
{1: 'one', 2: {-3: 'minus three', 4: 'four'}}
```

As we can see that **object_hook** is used to solve the problem, and **lstrip('-')** is used to handle negative values, too.

Comment: This is a much more generalizable solution. thanks