# Why does this Integer become a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So this little snippet of code takes an array `A` of integers and makes the integers strings when they become the keys of `pairs`.  Why?  Python is happy for them to remain integers, but JavaScript seems to only want strings for keys.

```
    var pairs = {};
    for(var i=0; i < A.length; ++i) {
        var value = A[i];
        if(pairs[value]) {
            delete pairs[value];
        } else {
            pairs[value] = true;
        }
    }
    console.log(A, pairs)
```

Produces:

```
Example test:    [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9]
Output:
[ 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9 ] { '7': true }
OK

Your test case:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Output:
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] { '10': true }
Returned value: 10
```

All the keys are integers when they are added to the pairs object, but they become strings when they are used as keys.  This is a good bit different from Python.

Comment: they have to be strings. see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings

Comment: See [Keys in Javascript objects can only be strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings) and [the documentation on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) ==> _Property names are Strings or Symbols. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string._

Comment: it's considered a `key` in a object, so, not a integer as in a value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450957/pythons-json-module-converts-int-dictionary-keys-to-strings#1450981

Answer (score 0):

By definition, object keys are always strings (or Symbols), if you use something else as a key it will be casted to a string. To have a Map in JS, there is `Map`, or a `Set` which will be enough in this case:

```
  const pairs = new Set();

 for(const value of [1, 2, 1])
   if(!pairs.delete(value)) pairs.add(value);

 console.log([...pairs]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `{}` is a literal expression for the Object type.  According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) objects map string names to values.

A datatype that accepts arbitrary values as keys is [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: There is. `Map`

Comment: Actually, `Map` _is_ a built-in dictionary type that accepts anything, including symbols, as keys.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Object keys are always strings. E.g.

```js
let x = {};
x.a = 1;
x[2] = 2;
x[x] = 3;

console.log(x);
```

On the other hand, if you want integer indices, you can use arrays instead

```js
let A = [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9];
var pairs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
  var value = A[i];
  if (pairs[value]) {
    delete pairs[value];
  } else {
    pairs[value] = true;
  }
}
console.log(A, pairs.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
  if (v) acc.push(i);
  return acc;
}, []));
```