# Why does my JSON create multiple entries instead of updating them?

Tags: json, discord, discord.py

I have a command where you can enter a correct answer. If it is correct, the user is credited with points in a JSON. But my update function seems to be broken, because after another correct execution an entry is made again in the JSON for the same user. However, I just want the points to update. Also, the JSON stops after the second entry about the user. What was wrong?

***Code:***

```py
correct_answers = "A"

# Open the JSON after start
def json_open():
    with open('users.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        return users


class Questions(commands.Cog, name='Question'):
    """Question bot"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.command()
    async def question(self, ctx, answer):
        self.question.enabled = False
        global correct_answers
        if correct_answers != answer:
            await ctx.author.send(f"You guessed {answer} which is **wrong**. Good luck next time!")
            await ctx.message.delete()
            return
# OPEN JSON FILE, LOAD DATA
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await self.update_data(users, ctx.message.author)
        await self.add_experience(users, ctx.message.author, 10)
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
            await ctx.message.delete()
# UPDATE DATA
    async def update_data(self, users, user):
        if not user.id in users:
            users[user.id] = {}
            users[user.id]['Points'] = 0
            #users[user.id]['level'] = 1

    async def add_experience(self, users, user, exp):
        users[user.id]['Points'] += exp
```

It looks like the last functions do not work or is the `add_experience` function not needed?

The JSON looks like this after the second execution:

```py
{"MYID": {"Points": 10}, "MYIDAGAIN": {"Points": 10}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it is converted into a `str` so you have to update the function a bit. To explain it better:
Turn the `user.id` into a `str`.

```py
    async def update_data(self, users, user):
        key = str(user.id)
        if key not in users:
            users[key] = {}
            users[key]['Points'] = 0

    async def add_experience(self, users, user, exp):
        users[str(user.id)]['Points'] += exp
```

Maybe also have a look at the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450957/pythons-json-module-converts-int-dictionary-keys-to-strings) where the problem is explained.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to string the user ID like this

```
users[str(user.id)]['Points'] += exp
```

Comment: This gives me a `KeyError` with my UID somehow.

Comment: That might mean that it didn't find the UID in the json file. To fix that you can do `except KeyError:  users[str(user.id)]['Points'] = exp`